# HSQLDB error when querying a @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hsqldb, many-to-one

I have two entities viz. InvoiceItem and ChargeCategory, defined using JPA semantics, with `@Column` on the getters. The InvoiceItem#getChargeCategory() is defined as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "item_charge_category")
public ChargeCategory getChargeCategory()
{
    return chargeCategory;
}
```

Now, when I try to retrieve all the InvoiceItems with a given item_charge_category as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM InvoiceItem i 
WHERE i.chargeCategory.itemChargeCategory = :itemChargeCategory
```

I get an error

```
Unexpected token: CROSS in statement
```

and the statement is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    <Columns from InvoiceItem>
FROM   dist_invoice_items Invoicei0_
       CROSS JOIN invoice_charge_types Chargec1_ 
WHERE  Invoicei0_.item_charge_category = 
       Chargec1_.item_charge_category 
       AND Chargec1_.item_charge_category = ?
```

I am using

- Hibernate: 3.5.5
- HSQLDB: 2.0

and persistence.xml is

```
<persistence-unit name="fssPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
</persistence-unit>
```

Did anyone face a similar issue? Any idea how to correct this? Please let me know if any further information would be helpful to address this.

Comment: Could you post your persistence.xml? Also, have you considered trying newer versions of hibernate and/or hsqldb?

Comment: Updated the question with persistence.xml. When I upgrade to HSQLDB 2.2, I am facing a different problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605835/hsqldb-2-2-skipping-certain-entities-and-not-creating-tables-for-them